# The sequence in string value (created by string_agg) in table_A is altered when join into table_B

Tags: postgresql, metabase

I encountered a very weird issue recently with PostgreSQL (in metabase environment, as I don't have access to database directly)

In table_A,  I use string_agg() to combine a series of string into one string in certain order, e.g. "A > B > C" or "3.5 > 4 > 5.6", and the result is correct and consistent in table_A.

However, when I use left join table_A in table_B,  the sequence in the string is altered, e.g.  "A > C > B", and even worse, the change of sequence appears randomly, i.e. sometimes "A > C > B", sometimes "B > A > C", and never seem to be correct.

I am not sure if it is metabase issue or my script issue.  Your knowledge will be much appreciated !

In order to make sure it is not complicated by script in Table_B and too many columns / values from Table_A, I simplified the script in Table_B, and only import/join one column and one record, the problem is still the same

e.g.

select B.id,  A.string
from table_B B
left join table_A A on A.id = B.id
where B.id = '123'

Result:
123 | 'B >C >A'   // but expect: 123 | 'A >B >C'

Comment: OK, noted that, it is not the join problem.  it is still the table_A problem.   There are multiple subqueries (with xxx as ( ... ... ) in table_A ).  if I specify the id (i.e. where id = '123') in earlier subqueries, the result is correct, whereas if I specify the id at last or not specify the id), the result is incorrect.   Let me figure about myself

Comment: Without order, there is no order. Always use ORDER BY when you need something ordered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order of a result set depends on the query execution plan that the database chooses. If you use an aggregate function like `string_agg()`, rows are aggregated in the order they happen to be produced by the query plan. If you need a certain fixed order, you have to be explicit about it:

```
string_agg(col, ',' ORDER BY col)
```

Comment: Wow,  magic.  that solves my problem straight away !  Thanks !